# How would you install a DIY kick plate for this dishwasher gap?

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher

Just had this dishwasher installed recently, and need to figure out what to do with the gap below it. Is it as simple as laying down two white pieces of wood (one longer one across and a tiny piece on the right side)?

[image: Dishwasher with Gap beneath it] [image: Lower View]

Comment: Kick plates are just decorative, unless kicking them.  Your idea should work, just make sure of clearance for the door opening and use attachments(small nails) so easy to remove.

Comment: Clearance is likely to be an issue. Try a mockup with cardboard before you commit.

Comment: Model # of dishwasher?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact SHEM3AY55N

Comment: Thanks for the comments on clearance! Cardboard mockup is a good idea.

Comment: Why do this?  It's black on purpose.   Dirt and moisture collect there.  You should try to keep it dry and clean, but if you make it white, you'll forever be staring at the grossness under there.   Especially after reading this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like there's already a *kickplate.*  You just need something to fill up the gap between the tile and the kickplate.  Consider a piece of hardwood/laminate floor transition or T-molding in an appropriate color.

As an aside, it looks to me like the feet could use some adjustment, or a piece of material placed in the floor space to elevate it slightly—you have a fair gap at the soffit.

Comment: That's good feedback - thank you. Good point about the kickplate already being installed there.

Comment: Missing *floor*, not toe kick, +1. Could put stand offs and longer screws to bring it forward, but there's a reason there's *toe kick space*. ... Or pull the fridge away from the wall. Or pull it totally out, do some tile, and then it can go all the way back. - Oh that's the DW... man, they didn't pull the DW?.... Guys, common.

Comment: @Mazura fridge?